# Getting apksigner error - MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET while uploading apk file in Google Play store

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, apk, visual-studio-cordova

Getting below error while uploading .apk file in Google Play Store

`ERROR: MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET: Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2; the APK is not signed with this or a later signature scheme`

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to build cordova mobile application, Target API Level is 30

Comment: What is the target-sdk that you've set in the config?

Comment: target-sdk is 30

Answer (score 2):

you need to use apksigner (found in Android Studio at Android/sdk/build-tools/version_number/lib/) to sign your app after aligning it with zipalign. Then you can upload yourappname.apk to Google Play and it will resolve the issue:

```
    cordova build android --release

    zipalign -f 4 platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk yourappname.apk

    apksigner sign --ks your-android-release-key.keystore --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true yourappname.apk
```